# Horizontal menu: How to get li items side by side (no whitespace)?

Tags: css, less

I want the list elements to be side by side. I don't want any space between the top and bottom of the div. When I hover a link I want the background color to change and it must be the height of the whole div. Sorry for my bad English. I'm using LESS. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="upper-links">
    <ul class="upper-nav">
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.upper-nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color:#003264;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.upper-nav li {
    display:inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color:#003264;
    padding:10px;
    vertical-align: center;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    .selected {
        background-color:#fff;
    }
     a:link, a:visited {
        background-color:#003264;
        color:#fff;
        display: inline-block;
        height:100%;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover, a:active {
        background-color:#fff !important;
        color:#003264;
        display: inline-block;
        height:100%;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: With a quick look, everything seems fine. Could you do a fiddle please? this would be easier... Or at least describe the exact problem... You want X, ok but what are you getting now? And what exactly is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting padding on your `<a>` elements, remove padding from `<li>` elements, and set a `box-sizing: border-box` for `<a>` elements to include their padding in their defined height

```
     .upper-nav{
        list-style-type: none;
        background-color: #003264;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
     }
     .upper-nav li{
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        background-color: #003264;
        vertical-align: middle;
        float: left;
        height: 50px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        .selected{
           background-color: #fff;
        }
        a:link, a:visited{
           background-color: #003264;
           color: #fff;
           display: inline-block;
           height: 100%;
           text-decoration: none;
           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
           box-sizing: border-box;
           padding: 10px;
        }
        a:hover, a:active{
           background-color: #fff !important;
           color: #003264;
           display: inline-block;
           height: 100%;
           text-decoration: none;
           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
           box-sizing: border-box;
           padding: 10px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Removing padding from li and adding padding to a did the trick. Thanks!